# iPhone Mobile Safari: Force keyboard open

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, mobile, safari

This is an HTML / CSS / JS (jQuery) iPad app. I've got a button, that slides down an input form. I'd like to focus the user on the input, and then launch the keyboard.

This is what I'm working with, but doesn't work:

```
$('#myFormField').focus();
```

This does indeed focus the input, but fails to launch the keyboard. Is it just not possible (for security reasons or whatever)?

Is there a way to force or simulate a user tapping the input (or anything for that matter)?

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738846/open-the-keyboard-of-an-ipad-through-javascript-on-a-non-text-field

Answer (score 4):

#### Try this

Tested on Safari iPhone 7 & iPhone 6 Plus, Android 4.4

and it opened iOS virtual keyboard successfully when I touched the button.

#### condition

1) make a Button to trigger keypress event => `$('.btn_abc')`

2) make a text input tag, and set the ID to this element => `$('#search_input')`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var focusTextField = function(){
    console.log("focusElement");
  };

  var onKeypressHandler = function(){
    console.log("* * * keypress event handler")
    $('#search_input').blur().focus();
  };

  var onClickHandler = function() {
    $('.btn_abc').trigger('keypress');
  };

  $('#search_input').bind('focus', focusTextField);
  $('.btn_abc').bind('click', onClickHandler);
  $('.btn_abc').bind('keypress', onKeypressHandler);

});
```

Comment: This worked for me on iPhone6 Plus, safari, ios 10.3.1.

Comment: Excellent. Working for me on iOS 11.3 (on an iPhone 6P and iPad Air, if that's of any consequence.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe these links can help you:

- [<del>http://4pcbr.com/topic/how_to_open_keyboard_on_ipad_with_js</del>](http://4pcbr.com/topic/how_to_open_keyboard_on_ipad_with_js) *(not working anymore)*
- http://jgestures.codeplex.com

Comment: using jgesture to auto open keyboard but this doesnt work `jQuery('#myTextBox').trigger("tapone");`

Comment: First link is returning 404.

Answer (score 2):

Turn that button into an input field then instantly swap focus to the main input field. They keyboard will open and stay opened. Below is an example using a button like you asked, placing a transparent input field over the button the user clicks. Tested on an iPhone 4 (iOS 6/7) and an HTC Windows phone.

The input you want the user to focus on:

```
<input id="main" />
```

The button the user presses (with input field overlayed using css):

```
<a>Button</a><input onfocus="FocusMain()" />
```

Swap focus instantly:

```
function FocusMain()
{
    $("#main").focus();
}
```

Comment: A demo would go a long way.

Comment: For me, using just $('objId').focus(); did the trick. I’m using it for a clear text box value button that originally cleared out the text box and the keyboard would annoyingly disappear too now the keyboard stays open. Awesome and thanks 

Answer (score -2):

This should do what you want:

```
$("#element").focus().click();
```

Comment: Doesn't work! I tried also, using setTimeout delay, and triggering the ontouchstart and ontouchend to simulate a touch on a input, but no progress.

Comment: this will not work... by design, phones do not allow showing keyboard on focus, a person needs to click on the input directly or use a focus() from within an onClick() event on another element

Comment: It's worth noting that this DID work at the time of posting, on the version of Safari which was current then.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$('#element').blur().focus();
```

or if that does not work:

```
$('#element').focus().blur().focus();
```

blur() eliminates the focus and focus() brings it back.  For some reason, it works every time compared to focus() working once in a while on its own.

Comment: same as above - this will not work... by design, phones do not allow showing keyboard on focus, a person needs to click on the input directly or use a focus() from within an onClick() event on another element

Comment: sorry, I have just realized that iPhone and iPad from iOS version 5 have ability for this to work, but Android certainly will chew on this