# Open the Keyboard of an iPad through JavaScript on a non-text field?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I have a div that acts as a textbox through some clever javascript. Yes, that smells, but it's vendor code I can't change :(

On an iPad, the Keyboard doesn't show because it's not a text field. Is there a way to force open the Keyboard through javascript, or decorate the HTML with something that tells Safari "Yes, this is really a textfield, just trust me!"?

Comment: I don't think it's possible I'm afraid... there are lots of people asking the same question: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+open+ipad+keyboard

Comment: If you can affect the page with javascript, you could create a text box that replaced the div...

Comment: @Charles True, but then i'd have to also add all the JavaScript logic that the vendor has in place. I can do that, but if there is a way to avoid it, it'd be great

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my experience there is no way to bring up the iPad or iPhone keyboard through Javascript. I ended up using a workaround that might be useful.

I simply place a text field with it's opacity set to 0 over the div in question. Then I update the div with the text field content on change.

like so ( using jQuery )

```
$('textarea').bind('input', function(e){
    var changedVal = $( e.currentTarget ).val();
    $('div').html( changedVal );    
});

// The input event is not a cross browser solution, use a combination of 
// keyboard and mouse events to correctly respond to any changes in the textarea
```

If your vendor code rely's on keyboard or mouse event listeners to do it's magic, you could proxy all the event types onto the div beneath.

Something like so ( using jQuery )

```
$('textarea').bind('keyup keydown keypress mouseup mousedown click', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget = $('div').get(0);
    $('div').trigger(e);
});
```